# What is the Namespace for CreateIfNotExists?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, azure

In my application I'm trying to upload the documents in to Azure blob storage. The code is:

```
// Namespaces for Azure
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient;

public ActionResult GetPdf(HttpPostedFileBase document)
{
    int pdfocument = Request.ContentLength;

    var doctype=Request.ContentType;

    byte[] pdf = new byte[pdfocument];               
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Setting1"));
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();           
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("containername");
    container.CreateIfNotExists();
    var permissions = container.GetPermissions();
    permissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob;
    container.SetPermissions(permissions);
    string uniqueBlobName = "blobname";
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(uniqueBlobName);
    blob.Properties.ContentType = doctype;
    blob.UploadByteArray(pdf);
}
```

When I build my application I get an error at `container.CreateIfNotExists()`. The error is:

> 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlobContainer' does not contain a definition for 'CreateIfNotExists' and no extension method 'CreateIfNotExists' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlobContainer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'.

Which namespace can I add for that error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CreateIfNotExists is part of version 2.0 of the Azure libraries.

If you are using the version 1.7 StorageClient namespaces then you need to call CreateIfNotExist (no plural)

Comment: Hi Rob,Your Information is correct.it's very usefult to me.for this am wasting couple of hours.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @PCSSCP, please mark it as the answer if it resolved your question.